select multiple cells inner join one table
please help me how to write query for these tables:
table_drive:



id
model




1
HDD 1TB


2
SSD 1TB


3
SSD 500


4
other



table_system:



name
drive_1
drive_2




system1
1
2


system2
3
1



select query output:



name
drive_1
drive_2




system1
HDD 1TB
SSD 1TB


system2
SSD 500
HDD 1TB



thanks;
i tried to join, but it results wrong output and i couldn't find correct query

You can generate this output by joining the table_system table to the table_drive table, twice:
SELECT ts.name, td1.model AS drive_1, td2.model AS drive_2
FROM table_system ts
LEFT JOIN table_drive td1
    ON td1.id = ts.drive_1
LEFT JOIN table_drive td2
    ON td2.id = ts.drive_2;


Could you please give a try to the given query.
SELECT s.name, d1.model AS drive_1, d2.model AS drive_2
FROM table_system s JOIN table_drive d1 ON s.drive_1 = d1.id
JOIN table_drive d2 ON s.drive_2 = d2.id;

This should works for you.

SELECT 
    system.name AS system_name, 
    drive1.model AS primary_drive, 
    drive2.model AS secondary_drive
FROM 
    table_system AS system
JOIN 
    table_drive AS drive1 ON system.drive_1 = drive1.id
JOIN 
    table_drive AS drive2 ON system.drive_2 = drive2.id;

